# manual pages for megatools

Tags: cloud, mega

I am trying to get smart with megatools/megacmd.
I can see all these commands installed in my system:

*mega-attr            megadf               mega-import          mega-mount           mega-share
mega-backup          megadl               mega-invite          mega-mv              mega-showpcr
mega-cancel          mega-du              mega-ipc             mega-passwd          mega-signup
mega-cat             mega-errorcode       mega-killsession     mega-permissions     mega-speedlimit
mega-cd              mega-exclude         mega-lcd             mega-preview         mega-sync
mega-cmd             mega-exec            mega-log             mega-put             megasync
mega-cmd-server      mega-export          mega-login           megaput              mega-thumbnail
mega-confirm         mega-find            mega-logout          mega-pwd             mega-transfers
mega-confirmcancel   mega-ftp             mega-lpwd            mega-quit            mega-tree
megacopy             mega-get             mega-ls              megareg              mega-userattr
mega-cp              megaget              megals               mega-reload          mega-users
mega-debug           mega-graphics        mega-mediainfo       mega-rm              mega-version
mega-deleteversions  mega-help            mega-mkdir           megarm               mega-webdav
mega-df              mega-https           megamkdir            mega-session         mega-whoami*

However for most of them there is no man page. I cannot find any deeper manual online. Do not know it these commands have options. Some i cannot guess what they really do. Can anyone tell me where are these commands well documented?

Thx a lot ...

Comment: Which version of Ubuntu are you using?

Comment: Ubu 19.10. Is it relevant for the megatools version?